# Does NEC allow a hardwired hood to be converted to plug in?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cord-and-plug, hood

I have a GE Cafe CVW73014MWM hood and from the factory, it is set to be installed hardwired.
Ideally, I would like it to be plug in. What does the 2018 NEC code state about this? Does the hood wiring have to meet a specific UL rating for conversion to plug in?

I'd like to avoid the need for a lockout at the panel which I was told would be a requirement of a hardwired hood.

Comment: what is your motivation to switch from hardwired to plug

Comment: This is a requirement that would only apply the once every several years that you work on the hood, so why is it a big deal?

Comment: NEC is in 3 year cycles - 2014, 2017, 2020 - no 2018. Actually, Google is finding *some* references, but almost everything says 2014, 2017, 2020.

Comment: What does the manual say about it?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - NFPA 70E is on a three year cycle including 2018, so perhaps they are confused between 70 and 70E?

Answer (score 17):

The decider here is the labeling and instructions.

When UL lists the item, they approve the labeling and instructions. They will say whether the unit is certified for hardwire vs cord-and-plug.